# WebAPI registered in new v2 endpoint does not prompt consent screen

Tags: azure-active-directory

An app registered in the v2 app registration portal, with a webapi platform added, however when requesting the authorisation with api scope using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` endpoint, it directly go to the redirect url with error code `AADSTS70002%3a+Error+validating+credentials`. Instead if I use the graph api, everything works, not sure what did I did wrong!

The one for the webapi scope:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=222db0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20api%3A%2F%2Fc6599db0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020%2Faccess_as_user`

The one for the graph api:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=222db0b0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read`

**EDIT**

This is confusing, now I put the offline and open id to the end but get another error:

`AADSTS65005%3a+The+application+'v2app'+asked+for+scope+'openid'+that+doesn't+exist+on+the+resource.+Contact+the+app+vendor.`

The URL I requested is:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/e0582222da8-ec2b-4c7a-b98e-2c417627657c/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=c6599db0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest&response_mode=query&scope=api%3A%2F%2Fc6599db0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020%2Faccess_as_user%20openid%20offline_access`

And if I google this error, [there is one saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254631/msal-error-message-aadsts65005-when-trying-to-get-token-for-accessing-custom-api):

> As of today, the V2 Endpoint does not support API access other than the Microsoft Graph.

So this is not achievable? Then how come [the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) works?

**EDIT 2**

So if I make the requested scope the client ID, it works..

Comment: Can you share the working URL you used for edit 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your error . but if putting the `openid%20offline_access` scopes after `api%3A%2F%2Fc6599db0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020%2Faccess_as_user`(api scope) , it works on my side , please try  :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=222db0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest&response_mode=query&scope=api%3A%2F%2Fc6599db0-0305-4f86-96cc-d283da2f5020%2Faccess_as_user%20openid%20offline_access
```

**Update**

The MSAL error you linked is accessing a Web API from a client that has a `different` Application ID , that is not supported in v2.0 endpoint . In azure ad v2.0, Web API can receive tokens only from an application that has the same Application ID. That means api://xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx (web api url) , the xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx part has the same value with your client id of client application . To achive that , you could add two platforms : one web app ,one web api .

Comment: thanks, could you please help review my edit, I got another error after your advice

Comment: in other words, I can only call the v2 hosted webapi within the webapp of the same application, any other way, e.g. a windows universal app or console app or any other cloud app but not same application will fail, correct? thanks!!!

Comment: @TOMMYWANG Yes .

Comment: this is sad, essentially any webapi on v2 would be of no use, if can only get called by the web app, why do i need a webapi after all..

Comment: Let me explain more , windows universal app/ console app(native app) or any other cloud app(web app) which have same application id with  web api , can call the web api , that means if you register web app in portal , then any cloud app with same application id can call the web api , if you register native application , then any windows universal app/ console app(native app) can also call the web api .